# preg_match_all, find all instances of exact match that contains special characters as string e.g. *** and add class

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am trying to create a function that is used to clean up some content and center instances where an exact match is found, replace it with a span and add a class to it. I have a base function, but I cant seem to figure out the correct syntax to use as the matches contain *** characters.

e.g. `<strong>* * *</strong>`

I have tried to be as detailed as possible, I really hope it all makes sense, if not please dont just down mark the questions, please explain why so I can improve the question and help someone else.

I have looked all over stack overflow questions before posting this comment as I know their are quite a lot of questions based around preg_match_all, but none that really fit my situation. I am struggling to figure out the pattern to use when the content has special characters, i think thats the first issue, second is my function below is probably not the best way, but being the amateur I am this is what made sense.

See my function below, this is what I have tried by looking at other answers on stack overflow and forums.

```
function content_format_stars($str = null) {
      if( !empty($str) ) {

        $pattern = "#<strong[^>]*>(.*?)</strong>#";

        $matches = array();

        if(preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER) !== false){

          $key = '* * *';

          if($matches) {

            foreach($matches as $match) {

              if ($match[1] == $key) {

                $br = '<span class="crb-content-divider">* * *</span>';

                $new_str = str_replace($match[0], $br, $str);

                return $new_str;

              }

            }

          } else {
            return $str;
          }

        } else {
          return $str;
        }
      }
    }
```

The expected result should be that it looks through the content and finds any occurrences of exactly this string `<strong>* * *</strong>` and replace it with `<span class="crb-content-divider">* * *</span>`. The string that is used is raw content from the database, exactly what would be the output of the_content() function in wordpress php template.

*UPDATE:*

Here is an example of the $str input:

```
<p>The structure of the work will be familiar to those obliged to read books produced by columnists and broadcast-media figures: a series of mostly disconnected essays and vignettes repackaged as a monograph, lightly stitched up with newly written connective material and punctuated every fourth page or so by something the author doesn’t realize is hilariously stupid or obviously wrong. As with chainsaw sculpture, the process leaves its mark on the product: columns and essays are arranged in a particular order and then written through (sometimes by the author, often by a junior editor) two or three times until the recycled material smells fresh enough to put a cover and title on. Wright has spent decades writing about the politics and <strong>personalities</strong> of Texas, and this book is a kind of greatest-hits album underneath a thin wash of the now-familiar indignant moral hysteria induced in the NPR crowd by the Age of Trump.</p>

<p><strong>* * *</strong></p>
```

The above is just a snippet, the content is much longer, and in some cases their are multiple instances of `<p><strong>* * *</strong></p>`. So the current function is returning any instance of `<strong></strong>`, and from my limited and basic understanding i built it out like you see above.

Comment: As you have `$key = '* * *';`, wouldn't this already be looking for the content with spaces, should it be `$key = '***';`?

Comment: Ye, but this is actually not working, it messes up all the content, I am really new to this, i cant even remember what my code looked like before it got to this point :(

Comment: This is the outcome of probably over 6 hours + of testing and going through stackoverflow comments.

Comment: Can you give an example of your input text and what you want as output, this helps testing the code.

Comment: @NigelRen, updated the code to show an example. Thanks so much for the replies guys!

Comment: If you just want to change `<strong>* * *</strong>` to `<span class="crb-content-divider">* * *</span>`, then use `str_replace('<strong>* * *</strong>', '<span class="crb-content-divider">* * *</span>', $str);.  You would only really need to use regex if you wanted to process the bit in-between the span tags.

Comment: Your code works fine!

Comment: @Toto, problem is that what happens when it matches instances where the strong tag is around text, it will then break the content and not return anything?